# Plural of "uh-oh" and "oh-no"

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe

Does the plural form of *uh-oh* and *oh-no* include an apostrophe? So is it "uh-oh's and oh-no's" or "uh-ohs and oh-nos"?

I've seen it both ways and cannot find a definitive answer anywhere.

Comment: I've also seen the plural of *cat* use an apostrophe. That does not mean anything. Plurals in English do not use apostrophes, period. The only exception is when you are building a plural of a highly unusual word, such as a single letter, and it could be confused with a different, well-established word. So for example you'd write *A's* to distinguish it from *as*. (Though even that is a matter of style; some style guides will tell you to go ahead and use *As* anyway.) *Uh-ohs* cannot be possibly confused with anything, however, so there are absolutely no excuses left to throw in an apostrophe.

Comment: I can't quite agree with Reg. Some authorities license no's, do's and ex's; this is to avoid the awkward-looking nos, dos and exs rather than any confusion (capitalisation distinguishes DOS). (No, do and ex are only 'highly unusual' in the form a regular plural would take / takes, of course.) By extension, this would argue for oh no's also being licensed; you'll have to decide on whether or not uh-hos looks acceptable. I'd use an apostrophe (but then I also use a semicolon as a 'super-comma' if I think it makes sense).

Comment: As regards pluralising **no**, I'd expect this to follow the same pattern as **do**. Google Books claims over 1M instances of ["the **do's** and {the don'ts}"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+do's+and%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), compared to only 92K for ["the **does** and"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+does+and%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (many if not most of which are irrelevant references to female deer anyway). Ignore 41 instances of ["the dos and the donts"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+dos+and+the+donts%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Off the top of my head, I'd say that the use of the word 'do' informally to mean an arranged party or 'bash' (a works do) was once more common hereabouts (Manchester) than that of do as in do's and don'ts.

Comment: @Edwin: I'm not sure the precise sense would materially affect the way it was pluralised. You're highly unlikely to say (*write*, I mean) *"I'm going to a couple of office **dos** next month"*. And to be honest, I suspect more people would write ***do's*** there than ***does*** (for obvious reasons which don't actually apply to *noes/no's*).

Comment: Yes - I was just putting forward a variant of _do_ that was further away from the word-as-a-word usage. Truss says these may _all_ be pluralised by italicising and adding 's: There are too many _aardvark_'s in this sentence.

Answer (score 4):

I asked my meme-minded son to check his texts. In this little electronic corpus, he found seven instances of "oh noes!!!" with no hyphen, no apostrophe, and too many exclamation points.

An official source is [Merriam-Webster's New Words and Slang](http://nws.merriam-webster.com/opendictionary/newword_display_alpha.php?letter=O&last=100), which includes *oh noes*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason the plural should use an apostrophe in the "uh-oh" case.  Indeed, if we check [google ngrams for "uh-oh's" vs "uh-ohs"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uh-ohs,%20uh-oh%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), we see that there is no usage of "uh-oh's", but some (and increasing!) usage of "uh-ohs".  Furthermore, use of "ohs" is far more common that of "oh's" (as seen [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oh%27s,%20ohs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)).

However, in the "oh-no" case, an apostrophe might be appropriate.  We can see that "no's" is the most common plural of "no" [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nos,%20no%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

I'd also like to mention that, while "uh-oh" is far more common that "uh oh", it seems that "oh no" is actually the more common form of that interjection, as can be seen [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oh%20no,%20oh-no&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), so the most proper plurals might be "uh-ohs" and "oh no's", respectively.

Comment: Oh course Google is there to save the day. Thank you for such a helpful answer.

Comment: If you like the answer, you could up-vote and/or check it!

Comment: I think you're being misled by the fact that NGrams doesn't work very well with hyphens and apostrophes. In Google Books, which treats them differently, I get ["uh-ohs"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22uh-ohs%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):742, ["uh-oh's"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22uh-oh's%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):648. Statistically speaking, no significant difference.

Comment: Confirm FF comment, hyphens and apostrophes have a habit of being "ignored" by Google books. Results will display both hyphenated and unhyphenated instances.

Answer (score 2):

A cursory googling suggests 73000 results for "oh-no's", 113000 for "oh-nos"  and 2170000 for "oh-noes" — however, the latter has become a meme, skewing the numbers.  The dictionary lists plurals for "no" of "noes" (first) and "nos" (second).  I also find I'm getting annoyed by the massive overuse of apostrophes in the world, but that's not quite germane.

I'd suggest "oh-noes" or "oh-nos", or "oh-no"s if you're a radical.

Comment: While the memification of "oh-noes" makes your data useless, I'm giving you a +1 for the radical suggestion because it amuses me.

Comment: Er, *which* dictionary?

Comment: Webster's Universal Encyclopedic Dictionary, 2002 edition, ISBN 0-7607-2911-5, p 1236: "plural noes or nos".